# Regex matching string formatted as @ or # followed dot-separated string containing no spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for a JavaScript regex that matches a string starting with a # or @ followed by a string containing only one dot / period (full stop) and no spaces. Note that there must be characters on either side of the dot, and the strings may contain multiple _ characters.  So,

```
"@xxxx.yyyyyy" = match
"@x.yyyyy" = match
"a@xxxxx.yy" = fail because first character not @ or #
"@@xxxxx.yy" = fail because it contains 2 @ characters
"@#xxxxx.yy" = fail because it contains 2 @ of the characters @ or # and should contain only 1
"@xxxxx.yy#" = fail same reason
"  @xx yyyyyy" = fail because it contains a space.
"#x_x.y_y" = pass 
"@_._" = fail because no a-z chars are present
"@_.y" = fail because no a-z chars present on left of dot.
```

I believe the use case here is quite common. I am seeking to establish whether a string contains a valid reference to a variable of the form @aaa_aaa_aaaaa.bb_b_bb, where the 'a' portion represents a query and the 'b' portion represents a column. The @ is a leading trigger to indicate the intention that the string is a variable. The '#' case is the same general intent except the '#' signifies a localisation string with the 'a' portion being a topic and the 'b' potion being the specific string.

I am by no means a regex guru and have been caught out before using online generators and misunderstanding some of the nuances. So far I have this but I'm struggling to limit the period to only one and I do not know how to apply a negative whitespace rule.

```
^(@|#)[a-zA-Z.]*
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

EDITS:

1. Thanks for pointing out I should have said 'starts with # or @'
2. The dot IS mandatory. Also at least one character either side of the dot.
3. A further use case has arisen: - there may also be multiple '_' (underscore) characters on both sides (either or both) of the dot. Example: '@aa_aaa_a.bb_bb'.

Thank you for the responses - I think all would have worked but I can only mark one as the correct answer so I have picked one and given the others an upvote.

Comment: Can the dot be at the end? Do there have to be chars a-z?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your requirements, you can use this regex,

```
^[@#][^@.#\s]+\.[^@.#\s]+$
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7dHpkt/1/)**

```js
const list = ['@xxxx.yyyyyy','@x.yyyyy','a@xxxxx.yy','@@xxxxx.yy','@#xxxxx.yy','@xxxxx.yy#','@xx yyyyyy']

list.forEach(s => {
console.log(s, ' --> ', /^[@#][^@.#\s]+\.[^@.#\s]+$/.test(s))
})
```

Also, in case you want to be restrictive about the allowed characters in your dot separated string, you can use `[a-zA-Z]` instead of a generic character set that I have used which is `[^@.#\s]` and in that case your regex becomes,

```
^[@#][a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+$
```

**Explanation:**

`^` - Start of string
`[@#]` - Match either `@` or `#` as the first character
`[a-zA-Z]+` - Match at least one letter to make it a DOT SEPARATED string
`\.` - Match a literal dot
`[a-zA-Z]+` - Again match at least one letter to make it a DOT SEPARATED string
`$` - End of string

[Demo2](https://regex101.com/r/7dHpkt/2/)

```js
const list = ['@xxxx.yyyyyy','@x.yyyyy','a@xxxxx.yy','@@xxxxx.yy','@#xxxxx.yy','@xxxxx.yy#','@xx yyyyyy']

list.forEach(s => {
console.log(s, ' --> ', /^[@#][a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(s))
})
```

**Edit:**

For allowing `_` in addition to alphabets in dot separated string, just include `_` within those square brackets and the regex you can use is this,

```
^[@#][a-zA-Z_]+\.[a-zA-Z_]+$
```

[Demo with underscores included](https://regex101.com/r/7dHpkt/3/)

Comment: @silanas - thank you for the prompt response. I cannot see anything wrong with your answer - sounds like faint  praise but you know what I mean, pesky regex are hard to foresee all the use cases. One question though, I see that I need to widen my case slightly to include the postential for [a-zA-Z] either side of the dot, but also that either side may contain the '_' (underscore) character. I will edit the question to include this - how would your regex change in that case ?

Comment: @VanquishedWombat: If you just want to allow underscore too in addition to alphabets, then just include `_` within character set and change `[a-zA-Z]` to `[a-zA-Z_]` Let me update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for adding the underscore solution.

Answer (score 1):

This regex does the job:

```
/^[@#][a-z]+(?:\.[a-z]+)?$/i
```

with optionnal dot.

If the dot is mandatory, use:

```
/^[@#][a-z]+\.[a-z]+$/i
```

```js
var test = [
    "@xxxx.yyyyyy",
    "@x.yyyyy",
    "a@xxxxx.yy",
    "@@xxxxx.yy",
    "@#xxxxx.yy",
    "@xxxxx.yy#",
    "   @xx yyyyyy",
];
console.log(test.map(function (a) {
  return a + ' :' + a.match(/^[@#][a-z]+(?:\.[a-z]+)?$/i);
}));
```

Comment: This matches `@aaa` which shouldn't as OP want's it to match **dot separated string**

Comment: @Silvanas: It's not said that the dot is mandatory but you may be right, wait for clarification.

Comment: Well, when a dot separates a string then at least one character must be present at both the sides. Also none of the samples present in OP's post further strengthen it. But you could be right too :) BTW good quick solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your question states `a string starting with a * or @` but I assume that is a `#` instead.

Another option is to match 0+ times the character class using `*` in front of the dot and follow by reating 1+ times the character class after the dot:

```
^[@#][a-zA-Z]*\.[a-zA-Z]+$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[@#]` Match `@` or `#`
- `[a-zA-Z]*` Match 0+ times a char a-zA-Z
- `\.[a-zA-Z]+` Match a literal dot and 1+ times a-zA-Z
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XmIa79/1)

```js
const pattern = /^[@#][a-z]*\.[a-z]+$/i;
["@xxxx.yyyyyy",
  "@x.yyyyy",
  "@x.yyyyy.",
  "a@xxxxx.yy",
  "@@xxxxx.yy",
  "@#xxxxx.yy",
  "@xxxxx.yy#",
  "#xxxx.yyyyyy",
  "#x.yyyyy",
  "#x.yyyyy.",
  "##xxxxx.yy",
  "##xxxxx.yy",
  "##xxxxx.yy",
  "#xxxxx.yy#"
].forEach(s => console.log(s + " --> " + pattern.test(s)));
```

Answer (score 1):

this is what you need, it will check for having `@` or `#` at the beggining and then it will match for `a-zA-Z` OR a `.` character and continue checking for letters.

```js
var test = [
  "@xxxx.yyyyyy",
  "@x.yyyyy",
  "a@xxxxx.yy",
  "@@xxxxx.yy",
  "@#xxxxx.yy",
  "@xxxxx.yy#",
  "   @xx yyyyyy",
];

const regex = new RegExp(/^[@#]([a-zA-Z]|\.)*$/i);

console.log(test.map(entry => `${entry}:  ${regex.test(entry)}`));
```